# How can I repopulate an array?

Tags: c#

I have code that populates an array:

```
var counters = new[] { 1,2,4,8 }
```

This works good but later on in my code I would like to do something like this:

```
counters = new[] { 2,2,3,5 }
```

Is there some way I can do this? I am very new to C# and still learning

Comment: You can do it just as you have written it... are you getting an error?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Yes, exactly the way you wrote it. But you'll have to add semicolons at the end of the lines.

Comment: Anyway, why would you do it? Did you consider using other data structures such as `List`, `Queue`, `Stack` and so on? In most cases they are better suitable for the task.

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote in your question would work fine: the first line will create a new array, the second line will also create a new array and will assign the new array to the existing variable.  The old integer array will be replaced (and later be garbage collected)

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem? Your code is valid:

```
    var counters = new[] { 1,2,4,8 };

    counters = new[] { 2, 2, 3, 5 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work, but it does not repopulate the array, it creates a new array.
You could do this

```
Array.Copy( new int[] { 2,2,3,5 }, counters, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do as you have written.

However, note that this will create a *new* array, not replace the values in the old array. That makes a difference if another variable holds a reference to the same array.

**Example 1**

```
var counters = new[] { 1, 2, 4, 8 };
var counters2 = counters;

counters = new[] { 2, 2, 3, 5 };

Console.WriteLine(counters2[0].ToString()); // outputs 1
```

**Example 2**

```
var counters = new[] { 1, 2, 4, 8 };
var counters2 = counters;

counters[0] = 2;
counters[1] = 2;
counters[2] = 3;
counters[3] = 5;  // or use Array.Copy as suggested by Henrik

Console.WriteLine(counters2[0].ToString()); // outputs 2
```